# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory even my class did have the jars

Tags: java

This took me some time to debug , but still no clue.

I am using m2e under Eclipse, I checked the java.class.path, it did have below jars on the classpath.

Any idea ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at hadoop.ReadHDFS.main(ReadHDFS.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more

C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.10\slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar
C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.10\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar
```

---add more context---

I am running the hadoop program. just found that when i add the hadoop-client dependency in the pom.xml, it will abort this error .

In the pom.xml , i did not explicitly add these dependencies but the effective pom have them and the java.class.path also include them.

Compile is good and only error in runtime

---workaround---

It will work if i excluded the slf4j-api from hadoop-client :
As for the root cause, still unknown.

Comment: Show your pom.xml please

Comment: Do those files actually exist?

Comment: how do you start your program? You show that you have the lib in your local maven repository, that does not put them on the classpath